# Finding The Sum of Odd Numbers From An Array

Tags: java, arrays, loops

My program is supposed to take the odd numbers from an array and count the number of times odd numbers occur in the array.

e.g.
countOdds({3, 7, 2, 4}) should return 2 as there are two odd numbers in the array.

```
public int countOdds (int[] values) {
int oddTotal=0;
for(int i=0;i<values.length;i++){
if(i%2!=0){
oddTotal=oddTotal+1;
}
}
return oddTotal;
```

I'm getting these as results:
[image: my results]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/e802b78671018a23b73402ecfeb9b994.png))</sub>

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code ?

Answer (score 7):

You are checking your counter `i` instead of the value `values[i]`.

Comment: @NatalieCorfe-Tan If Keppil's suggestion helped you, you should accept the answer.  It's how this site works.

Answer (score 1):

```
public int countOdds (int[] values) {
int oddTotal=0;
if(values == null)
  return oddTotal;
for(int i=0;i<values.length;i++){
    if(values[i]%2!=0){
    oddTotal=oddTotal+1;
  }
}
return oddTotal;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int countOdds (int[] values) {
   int oddTotal=0;
   for(int i=0;i<values.length;i++) {
   if(values[i] % 2 != 0) {
       oddTotal=oddTotal+1;
   }
   return oddTotal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

- You're not checking anything in the array - you can do that with `values[i]`.
- What happens if your array comes in as null?  You will get a `NullPointerException`.  You may want to check for that:

  ```
  if(values == null) {
     return 0;
  }
  ```